# Not able to delete youtube video in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, youtube, youtube-data-api

I am trying to delete youtube video from ios app.I am using YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper for youtube API in my app. I am able to get list of videos and  video's ID in "videoId" parameter  but not able to delete the video.I followed the exact steps provided in the library.I was able to delete the playlist videos and playlists with same steps.

I am getting this response for the request:

response: Error Domain=com.google.GTLRErrorObjectDomain Code=400 "Required parameter: id" UserInfo={GTLRStructuredError=GTLRErrorObject 0x1702544f0: {message:"Required parameter: id" errors:[1] code:400}, NSLocalizedDescription=Required parameter: id}

But I am passing the id in the request. It would be really helpful if someone can point in the right direction or help me solve the issue.

Here is my code:

```
        self.servive.APIKey = self.apiKey;
        self.servive.authorizer = self.authorizer;
        GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosDelete *query = [GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosDelete queryWithIdentifier:id];
        [self.servive executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket ticket, GTLRYouTube_Video object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error)
            {
                NSLog(@"response: %@", object);
                completion(object,false);

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"response: %@", error);
                completion(nil,error);
            }
        }];
```

Comment: Are you logged in, in the youtube application?

Comment: Yes, I logged in from google using Google library and got the access Token and everything. I am able to do most of CRUD operations. I am only not able to delete the video.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to delete please

Comment: I have updated the question. You can check the code there now

Comment: Can you print id? or put a break point on  GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosDelete *query = [GTLRYouTubeQuery_VideosDelete queryWithIdentifier:id]; to see what it gives you

Comment: I have checked it and id is the id of youtube video. there is no error in it.